# How do I disable a QML ShaderEffect?

Tags: qt, qml, shader, fragment-shader

I have a shader that I'm running and I want to be able to disable the shader on the press on the button. I want to disable it so it doesn't use any extra resources. How can I achieve this? Here I have an example where a shader slowly fades in and out, and I want to disable the shader when you click the button on the top left. Right now, I get this exception:

`ShaderEffect: Property 'source' is not assigned a valid texture provider (std::nullptr_t).`

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    visible: true
    property bool shaderEnabled: true

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "gray"
        layer.enabled: shaderEnabled

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: qsTr("Hello")
            font.pixelSize: 40
            color: "blue"
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (shader.opacity > 0) {
                shader.opacity = 0
                console.log("Hiding")
            } else {
                shader.opacity = 1
                console.log("Showing")
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: shaderButton
        text: shaderEnabled ? "Disable shader" : "Enable shader"
        onClicked: {
            shaderEnabled = !shaderEnabled
        }
    }

    ShaderEffect {
        id: shader
        anchors.fill: parent
        property variant source: shaderEnabled ? rect : null
        Behavior on opacity { PropertyAnimation {} }
        opacity: 0
        fragmentShader: "
            varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
            uniform sampler2D source;
            uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
            void main() {
                gl_FragColor = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0) * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0) * qt_Opacity;
            }"
    }
}
```

Adding a `visible: ShaderEnabled` to the ShaderEffect seems to work but I still see the error message which leads me to believe that it's still using the resources. Would using a `Loader` help?

Comment: Instead of `null`, does it work if you use `undefined`?

Comment: @JarMan nope, I get this `ShaderEffect: Property 'source' is not assigned a valid texture provider ().`. I also added an enabled property to the shader but that doesn't seem to work because I still get this error.

Comment: @JarMan Adding a `visible: ShaderEnabled` to the ShaderEffect seems to work but I still see the error message which leads me to believe that it's still using the resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know Loader was mentioned, but, a clean way to avoid Loaders is by using a Repeater and a model. When shaderEnabled is true, it will instantiate a new ShaderEffect instance. When shaderEnabled is false, it will destroy that ShaderEffect instance. To implement this in your example, you will need to rework how you control opacity via a property similar to how you have done shaderEnabled.

```
Repeater {
    model: shaderEnabled ? 1 : 0
    ShaderEffect {
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Why is using a Loader bad? From my understanding this isn't the primary use of Repeaters?

Comment: Loaders aren't really bad per se, but misuse could lead to performance issue because it has to compile whatever you load at runtime. Here, everything in the Repeater is defined at compile time so it is strongly typed and well define. Another potential problem is unloading items from loaders isn't what you expect in fact to be successful you have to load a blank Item {} instead of clear source to force the ShaderEffect to unload.

Comment: Repeaters, are in fact designed to instantiate and destroy delegates related to changes in the model. It is an intrinsic feature of Repeaters and other components involving models. It is just not intuitively obvious that you can leverage this feature for creating and destroying your ShaderEffect, but, there is absolutely nothing wrong with the approach.

Answer (score 0):

I used a Loader to accomplish this. This way the shader component is created on demand and not created when it's not needed. Changing the source or sourceComponent also destroys the previously instantiated items.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15

Window {
    width: 1024
    height: 600
    visible: true
    property bool shaderEnabled: true
    property real shaderOpacity: 0

    Rectangle {
        id: rect
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "gray"
        layer.enabled: shaderEnabled

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: qsTr("Hello")
            font.pixelSize: 40
            color: "blue"
        }
    }

    MouseArea {
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            if (shaderOpacity > 0) {
                shaderOpacity = 0
                console.log("Hiding")
            } else {
                shaderOpacity = 1
                console.log("Showing")
            }
        }
    }

    Button {
        id: shaderButton
        text: shaderEnabled ? "Disable shader" : "Enable shader"
        z: 2
        onClicked: {
            shaderEnabled = !shaderEnabled
            console.log("Shader enabled ", shaderEnabled)
        }
    }

    Loader {
        id: effectLoader
        sourceComponent: shaderEnabled ? shaderComponent : undefined
        anchors.fill: parent
    }

//    Repeater {
//        model: shaderEnabled ? 1 : 0
//        ShaderEffect {
//            id: shader
//            anchors.fill: parent
//            property variant source: shaderEnabled ? rect : null
//            //visible: shaderEnabled
//            Behavior on opacity { PropertyAnimation {} }
//            opacity: shaderOpacity
//            fragmentShader: "
//                varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
//                uniform sampler2D source;
//                uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
//                void main() {
//                    gl_FragColor = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0) * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0) * qt_Opacity;
//                }"
//        }
//    }

    Component {
        id: shaderComponent

        ShaderEffect {
            id: shader
            property variant source: rect
            //visible: shaderEnabled
            Behavior on opacity { PropertyAnimation {} }
            opacity: shaderOpacity
            fragmentShader: "
                varying highp vec2 qt_TexCoord0;
                uniform sampler2D source;
                uniform lowp float qt_Opacity;
                void main() {
                    gl_FragColor = texture2D(source, qt_TexCoord0) * vec4(1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0) * qt_Opacity;
                }"
        }
    }
}
```